# MongoDB counting days per user

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create a query that counts how many times a user has done an action in a 1 month period.

This is the data format:

```
[
  {
    "happened": ISODate(2017-1-1),
    "user": ObjectId(a),
    "action": ObjectId(i)
  },
  {
    "happened": ISODate(2017-1-1),
    "user": ObjectId(a),
    "action": ObjectId(i)
  }
]
```

I want to find out how many times a user has done a certain action in a period of time.

I've figured out the `$match`:

```
{
  $match: {
    happened: { $gte: 2017-1-1, $lt: 2017-2-1 },
    action: i
  }
}
```

I've also been experimenting with the `$group` bit, but I can't figure out how to get what I want. This is what I have so far:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      user: "$user",
      year: { $year: "$happened" },
      day: { $dayOfYear: "$happened" }
    },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}
```

I want to see for each user how many days they perform the action. But I cannot get beyond this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "user": ObjectId(a),
      "year": ObjectId(2017),
      "day": ObjectId(1)
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "user": ObjectId(a),
      "year": ObjectId(2017),
      "day": ObjectId(2)
    },
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

You can see that I am getting the count of instances for each user, but it also shows per day. I want to see how many days for each user.

Comment: Each document has a date for action for each user. You have to just count them. Something like this `{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      user: "$user"
    },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
}
}`

Comment: The issue with that is that if they perform that action once on Monday and twice on Tuesday that counts as 3, I am trying to make it count as 2, one count per day for the member/action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

First `$group` to get distinct days for the each user followed by `$group` to `$push` the distinct days and `$project` to count the days.

```
{ $group: { _id: { user: "$user", day: { $dayOfMonth: "$happened" } } } },
{ $group: { _id: "_id.$user", days:{$push:"$_id.day"} } },
{ $project: { user:"$user", count: { $size: "$days" } } }
```

Comment: This worked, however adding `$sort: [ { count: -1 } ] ` didn't

Comment: Try `$sort:  { count: -1 }`

Comment: Yeah that was it, Mongoose versus Mongo... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the root document to a temporary array, [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) it and make a group again taking the first value for the previous calculated count of days :

```
db.data.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        happened: { $gte: ISODate("2017-01-01"), $lt: ISODate("2017-02-01") },
        action: "Action1"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$happened" }
        },
        dayCount: { $sum: 1 },
        doc: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$doc"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$doc.user",
        dayCount: { $first: "$dayCount" },
        actionCount: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}])
```

It gives you userId, dayCount (number of day where at least one action performed) and actionCount :

```
{ "_id" : "1", "dayCount" : 2, "actionCount" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "2", "dayCount" : 3, "actionCount" : 4 }
```

Comment: That returns an error about $push.

{ [MongoError: invalid operator '$push']
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'invalid operator \'$push\'',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'invalid operator \'$push\'',
  code: 15999 }

Comment: whats your mongodb version ?

Comment: Mongo Version: 3.2.6 (Thx for your help :D)

Comment: Are you using mongoDB shell ? Can you try with [these sample data](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/d2df79c772927397b8dedcb140c23b13) to see if it does run

Comment: It was using Mongoose, but even on 3.4.2 it is doing that. Your example did work however in the shell. Might be a mongoose issue, that said Veeram's code works but I can't get sorting yet.